# BOOST::CRC creating checksum with process.block() method

Tags: c++, boost, crc

I am currently trying to create a checksum over the length of a custom struct UMGR_s. I did use the BOOST::crc method process.block() with the start and end address of my struct.

The problem is that I will get a different checksum every time I run this method even though the data in the struct remains consistent. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
int checksum_manager::createCRC(UMGR_s *CRCdata)
{
    boost::crc_32_type result;

    result.process_block(CRCdata, CRCdata + 1);

    return result.checksum();
};
```

Comment: I found out that the problem is the struct and the padding that comes with it. The padding is used for alignment and seems to be random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking back at your older question:

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

struct UMGR_s {
    std::string name;
    std::string description;
    std::string dlt_id;
    std::string log_mode;
    std::string log_level;
    std::string log_dir_path;
    uint ipc_port;
    uint reconnection_retry_offset;
    uint msg_buf_size;
    int checksum;
};

static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<UMGR_s>{});
static_assert(not std::is_trivial<UMGR_s>{});
static_assert(not std::is_pod<UMGR_s>{});
```

This is not POD. Simply blitting the bits is not dependable as you have already noticed.

Treat it as a C++ object and write a checksum function e.g.:

```
int calcCRC() {
    boost::crc_32_type crc;
    crc.process_bytes(name.data(), name.size());
    crc.process_bytes(description.data(), description.size());
    crc.process_bytes(dlt_id.data(), dlt_id.size());
    crc.process_bytes(log_mode.data(), log_mode.size());
    crc.process_bytes(log_level.data(), log_level.size());
    crc.process_bytes(log_dir_path.data(), log_dir_path.size());
    crc.process_block(&ipc_port, &ipc_port+1);
    crc.process_block(&reconnection_retry_offset, &reconnection_retry_offset+1);
    crc.process_block(&msg_buf_size, &msg_buf_size+1);

    return crc.checksum();
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1381b7ab92804e32)**.

The example consistently returns `0xbf21e978`, and without [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) or valgrind/ASAN warnings.

Even better, make it less error-prone:

```
struct CRC {
    boost::crc_32_type crc;
    void operator()(std::string_view s) {
        crc.process_bytes(s.data(), s.size());
    }
    template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>>
    void operator()(T const& i) {
        static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<T>);
        static_assert(not std::is_class_v<T>);
        crc.process_bytes(&i, sizeof(i));
    }

    auto get() { return crc.checksum(); }
};
```

Which means you can now "just" write:

```
int calcCRC() {
    CRC crc;
    crc(name);
    crc(description);
    crc(dlt_id);
    crc(log_mode);
    crc(log_level);
    crc(log_dir_path);
    crc(ipc_port);
    crc(reconnection_retry_offset);
    crc(msg_buf_size);

    return crc.get();
}
```

### Live Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b68d2a29423230c1)**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/crc.hpp>

struct CRC {
    boost::crc_32_type crc;
    void operator()(std::string_view s) {
        crc.process_bytes(s.data(), s.size());
    }
    template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>>
    void operator()(T const& i) {
        static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<T>);
        static_assert(not std::is_class_v<T>);
        crc.process_bytes(&i, sizeof(i));
    }

    auto get() { return crc.checksum(); }
};

struct UMGR_s {
    std::string name;
    std::string description;
    std::string dlt_id;
    std::string log_mode;
    std::string log_level;
    std::string log_dir_path;
    uint ipc_port;
    uint reconnection_retry_offset;
    uint msg_buf_size;
    int checksum;

    int calcCRC() {
        CRC crc;
        crc(name);
        crc(description);
        crc(dlt_id);
        crc(log_mode);
        crc(log_level);
        crc(log_dir_path);
        crc(ipc_port);
        crc(reconnection_retry_offset);
        crc(msg_buf_size);

        return crc.get();
    }
};

static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<UMGR_s>{});
static_assert(not std::is_trivial<UMGR_s>{});
//static_assert(not std::is_pod<UMGR_s>{});

int main() {
    UMGR_s data {
         "UMGR",
         "UpdateManager",
         "1234",
         "kConsole",
         "kVerbose",
         "",
         33,
         0,
         1000,
         0,
    };

    data.checksum = data.calcCRC();

    std::cout << "crc: " << std::hex << std::showbase << data.checksum << "\n";
}
```

Observe that it still prints the same CRC:

```
crc: 0xbf21e978
```